# Database for small business - restricted w/multiple users

Tags: ms-access

What database software should I use that can:

- Allow users w/ restrictions based on each user
- Useful for small businesses
- Like MS Access

Comment: Define "useful for small business"

Comment: Ease of use, multiple users/computers accessing databases at the same time.  Scale-able

Comment: @user1218753: I wouldnt use any of those to describe MSAccess.

Comment: @prodigalson So what combination of database / front-end do you see as easier to use and maintain than MS Access?

Comment: SQL CE or SQL Express. SQL CE can only be up to 4 GB in size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I still think MSAccess is a good place to start, for a limited number of users it is perfectly suitable for multiple access and it is scaleable up to SQL-Server relatively easily.  The only major restriction is to refrain from using spaces in table and field names when/if you want to   migrate to SQL Server they will cause you grief.

wrt to different access for different users you will need to program this but then you will need to do that in whatever language you use.

Comment: why not use SQL Express or SQL CE? It's SQL friendly and meets all the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

It is not like MS Access but you can use either MySQL or PostgreSQL. Both are free to use and open source.

Comment: The main issue of course is writing code, building reports and also that of building forms and a UI. MySQL offers none of this.

Answer (score 0):

Try MS Access, or Oracle.
If you provide more details about where and how it will be used we can give a better answer.